# Почему проваливается тест?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Не могу понять как составить тест для метода, обновляющего товар.

Вот сам тест

```
@Test
public void updateProductFail(){
   Product product = new Product();
   product.setId(1L);
   product.setProductName("Horseradish - Prepared");

    boolean isProductUpdated = productService.updateProduct(product);

    assertFalse(isProductUpdated);
}
```

Вот тестируемый метод

```
 public boolean updateProduct(Product productForUpdate){
    // ищием товар с таким же именем в БД
    Product productFromDB = findProductByName(productForUpdate.getProductName());

    if (productFromDB != null){
        // если товар с таким именем нашёлся, проверяем, является ли это товар тем же самым
        if (productFromDB.equals(productForUpdate)){
            // если да, то обновляем данные и возращаем true
            productRepository.save(productForUpdate);
            return true;
        }else return false; // иначе false
    }

    // если товар не нашёлся, просто обновляем данные  и возращаем true
    productRepository.save(productForUpdate);
    return true;
}
```

Класс товара

```
package com.example.mywms.Model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product extends BaseEntity{

    @NotBlank(message = "Поле не должно быть пустым")
    private String productName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProductType productType;

    @NotBlank(message = "Поле не должно быть пустым")
    @Size(min = 10, max = 255, message = "Описание товара должно быть от 10 до 255 символов")
    private String productDescription;

    @Positive(message = "Цена товара не может быть меньше 0 или быть равной 0")
    private double productPrice;

    @PositiveOrZero(message = "Количесвто товара не может быть меньше 0")
    private int productStock;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProductStatus productStatus;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "product_delivery",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "delivery_id")
    )
    private Set<Delivery> deliveriesProductIn = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Product)) return false;
        Product product = (Product) o;
        return getId().equals(product.getId()) && getProductName().equals(product.getProductName());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + getProductName().hashCode();
        result = (int) (prime * result + getId());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Весь класс для теста

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ProductServiceTest {

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@MockBean
private ProductRepository productRepository;

@Test
public void saveProduct() {
    Product product = new Product();

    boolean isProductAdded = productService.saveProduct(product);

    assertTrue(isProductAdded);
    assertEquals(ProductStatus.FREE_TO_DELIVER, product.getProductStatus());

    Mockito.verify(productRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(product);
}

@Test
public void saveProductFail() {
    Product product = new Product();

    product.setProductName("Серёжки");

    Mockito.doReturn(product)
            .when(productRepository)
            .findByProductName("Серёжки");

    boolean isProductAdded = productService.saveProduct(product);

    assertFalse(isProductAdded);
}

@Test
public void updateProduct(){
    Product product = new Product();

    boolean isProductUpdated = productService.updateProduct(product);

    assertTrue(isProductUpdated);
}

@Test
public void updateProductFail(){
   Product product = new Product();
   product.setId(1L);
   product.setProductName("Horseradish - Prepared");

    boolean isProductUpdated = productService.updateProduct(product);

    assertFalse(isProductUpdated);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, нужно было сделать так

```
@Test
public void updateProductFail(){
   Product productForUpdate = new Product();
   productForUpdate.setId(1L);
   productForUpdate.setProductName("Horseradish - Prepared");

   Product product = new Product();
   product.setId(2L);
   product.setProductName("Horseradish - Prepared");

    Mockito.doReturn(product)
            .when(productRepository)
            .findByProductName("Horseradish - Prepared");

   boolean isProductUpdated = productService.updateProduct(productForUpdate);

    assertFalse(isProductUpdated);
}
```